# pandas read csv ignore newline

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

i have a dataset (for compbio people out there, it's a FASTA) that is littered with newlines, that don't act as a delimiter of the data.

Is there a way for pandas to ignore newlines when importing, using any of the pandas read functions?

sample data:

> >ERR899297.10000174
>   TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTATATATCTCAATTGCATGAATCATCGTATTAATGC
>   TATCAAGATCAGCCGATTCT

every entry is delimited by the ">"
data is split by newlines (limited to, but not actually respected worldwide 
with 80 chars per line)

Comment: Checkout the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html. Specifically the `skip_blank_lines` parameter

Comment: can you represent the data as a string and then replace the newlines?

Comment: data is 40GB+ 
representing the data as a string is not ideal.
python Iteration is also not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another sign which will tell pandas when you do actually want to change of tuple.

Here for example I create a file where the new line is encoded by a pipe (|) :

```
csv = """
col1,col2, col3, col4|
first_col_first_line,2nd_col_first_line,
3rd_col_first_line

de,4rd_col_first_line|
"""
with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(csv)
```

Then you read it with the C engine and precise the pipe as the lineterminator :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("test.csv",lineterminator="|", engine="c")
```

which gives me : 
[image]

Comment: This assumes that my data is delimited by commas.
My data is delimited by a single character ">", and the data is split into subsections with a newline

eg:
>ERR899297.10000174
TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTATATATCTCAATTGCATGAATCATCGTATTAATGC
TATCAAGATCAGCCGATTCT

What about read_fwf?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Comment: I tried that, but then I end up with this:
https://imgur.com/a/wUFeo
I can't reshape either, since the data isn't always going to be 2 rows.

Comment: I'm thinking this can't be done without cleaning up the data to be imported into DataFrames first, which is a shame.  

These files are 40GB+

Answer (score 1):

This should work simply by setting `skip_blank_lines=True`.

> skip_blank_lines : bool, default True
>
> If True, skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values.

However, I found that I had to set this to `False` to work with my data that has new lines in it. Very strange, unless I'm misunderstanding.

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this.
BioPython alone seems to be sufficient, over a hybrid solution involving iterating through a BioPython object, and inserting into a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for pandas to ignore newlines when importing, using any of the pandas read functions?

Yes, just look at the doc for [`pd.read_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html)

You want to specify a custom line terminator (`>`) and then handle the newline (`\n`) appropriately: use the first as a column delimiter with [str.split(maxsplit=1)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and ignore subsequent newlines with [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (until the next terminator):

```
#---- EXAMPLE DATA ---
from io import StringIO
example_file = StringIO(
"""
>ERR899297.10000174 
TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTATATATCTCAATTGCATGAATCATCGTATTAATGC
TATCAAGATCAGCCGATTCT
; this comment should not be read into a dataframe
>ERR123456.12345678
TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTATATATCTCAATTGCATGAATCATCGTATTAATGC
TATCAAGATCAGCCGATTCT
; this comment should not be read into a dataframe
"""
)
#----------------------


#---- EXAMPLE CODE ---
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(
    example_file,           # Your file goes here
    engine = 'c',           # C parser must be used to allow custom lineterminator, see doc
    lineterminator = '>',   # New lines begin with ">"
    skiprows =1,            # File begins with line terminator ">", so output skips first line 
    names = ['raw'],        # A single column which we will split into two
    comment = ';'           # comment character in FASTA format
)

# The first line break ('\n') separates Column 0 from Column 1
df[['col0','col1']] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.raw.apply(lambda s: s.split(maxsplit=1)))

# All subsequent line breaks (which got left in Column 1) should be ignored
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('\n',''))

print(df[['col0','col1']])

# Show that col1 no longer contains line breaks
print('\nExample sequence is:')
print(df['col1'][0])
```

Returns:

```
                 col0                                               col1
0  ERR899297.10000174  TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTA...
1  ERR123456.12345678  TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTA...

Example sequence is:
TGTAATATTGCCTGTAGCGGGAGTTGTTGTCTCAGGATCAGCATTATATATCTCAATTGCATGAATCATCGTATTAATGCTATCAAGATCAGCCGATTCT
```

Answer (score 0):

After `pd.read_csv()`, you can use `df.split()`.

```py
 import pandas as pd


 data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
 data.split()
```