# Reading csv file in pandas with newlines and natural language

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with multiple columns that contain numbers and natural language text. The columns have a special separator (say "%#") so that one can immediately see the boundary between columns. For example:

```
55%#This is an example text%#24
32%#This is another example text%#1649
```

However, sometimes the text contains newlines:

```
212%#This is a possible
occurrence of 
a text in the csv file%#3399
```

My problem is how to read the csv file with pandas such that the newline is not interpreted as another csv row. When I use `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='%#')` I get for example:

```
Col1                    Col2                  Col3
212                     This is a possible    None
occurrence of           None                  None
a text in the csv file  3399
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694790/pandas-read-csv-ignore-newline last answer not working ?

Comment: What you describe isn't a CSV file. Also, what is *actually the rule that tells you* whether a newline should be treated one way or the other?

Comment: You will need a custom parser to process that file.